# Identity and vectors in R: how does MyData1 == c("a", "b") work (or not)

Tags: r, vector, boolean-expression

I made a mistake and instead of writing `MyData1 %in% c("a", "b")`

...I wrote `MyData1 == c("a", "b")`

...but I'd like to know how and why this doesnt work. Why does the following happen?

```
> MyData1 <- rep(c("a", "b", "b"), 4)
> MyData1
 [1] "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "b"
> MyData1 == c("a", "b")
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Why is the first result TRUE and the second FALSE? Try:

```
> MyData1[1] == c("a", "b")
[1]  TRUE FALSE
> MyData1[2] == c("a", "b")
[1] FALSE  TRUE
> MyData1[1:2] == c("a", "b")
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

...I'm none the wiser...now I get two items back whether I test 1 or 2 elements of the vector!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of vector recycling. `==` does element wise comparison whereas `%in%` checks for the value in the entire vector and it does not matter where the position of that element is.

When one vector/value is shorter in length than the other one R recycles the value and makes them of equal length.

When you do

```
MyData1 == c("a", "b")
```

1st value in `MyData1` is compared with `"a"`, 2nd value in `MyData1` is compared with `"b"`. Now since the vector `c("a", "b")` is shorter R recycles the same values again so 3rd value of `MyData1` is compared with `"a"` again and 4th with `"b"` and so on.

In the next part again vector recycling happens but this time in opposite direction.

```
MyData1[1] == c("a", "b")
```

`MyData1[1]` is of length 1 so 1st value of `MyData1[1]` is compared with `"a"` and now the same value is repeated again to compare with `"b"` so that you get.

```
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```